# Javascript / jQuery- how to uncheck all the other checkboxes when clicking one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few checkboxes:

```
<input class="time" id="test_1" type="checkbox" name="test1" value=""> test1<br>    
<input class="time" id="test_2" type="checkbox" name="test2" value=""> test2<br>
<input class="time" id="test_3" type="checkbox" name="test3" value=""> test3<br>
<input class="time" id="test_4" type="checkbox" name="test4" value=""> test4<br>
<input class="time" id="test_5" type="checkbox" name="test5" value=""> test5<br>
```

What I intend to do is when `#test_1` is clicked, every other checkbox gets unchecked no matter if they are currently checked or not.

Something like:

```
$('#test_1').click(function() { 
  not $(this).attr('unchecked');
});
```

I don't know how to uncheck the checkboxes with jQuery. But I want to say, not this checkbox. So that every other checkbox is unchecked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no attribute named `unchecked` …

Comment: You're going to have explain that **a lot** better, the checkboxes are checked / unchecked by default when you click them, but when do you want to uncheck them programatically exactly? When a particular one is clicked, when any one of them is unchecked etc? It's very unclear.

Comment: Sounds like you want radio buttons, not checkboxes.

Comment: no sorry, I will edit because I was a little bit unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var $unique = $('input.time');
 $unique.click(function() {
 $unique.filter(':checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hsvF6/1/)**

Comment: thanks you got me, exactly what I wanted. Sorry for the sloppy explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily fix this by using radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

```
<input class="time" id="show_15min" type="radio" name="time" value="15min"> 15min <br>
<input class="time" id="show_28min" type="radio" name="time" value="28min"> 28min <br> 
<input class="time" id="show_45min" type="radio" name="time" value="45min"> 45min <br> 
<input class="time" id="show_60min" type="radio" name="time" value="60min"> 60min <br>
```

Comment: no that was not exactly what I was searching for because I want to only uncheck the other boxes when I'm ticking a specific one. Thanks!

Comment: In other words, only allow maximum one item to be checked at a time. That's what radio inputs are for.

Comment: no only one item is checked if I am ticking the first one. I edited my answer short time ago because it was unclear. I guess your post was before that. But I appreciate your help!